# Why Image.resolveAssetSource() is not returning the height and width in react native?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I recently moved to **react native** and want to get the size of the **uri** image. I looked at the **react native** [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image) and found [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#resolveassetsource) method:

```
Image.resolveAssetSource();
```

When I use it for **static images(require())** it works fine and return the height and width property along with other useful properties, but when i use it for the **dynamic images({uri: 'www.abc.com/image'})** it only and only returns the **uri** property containing in the object but not **height** and **width** properties.

I was thinking that may be I am doing something wrong, but in fact the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#resolveassetsource) mentioned that:

> ImageSource is an object like { uri: 'http location || file path' }

Then why it is not working for the **uri**? Can anyone tell?

Comment: Image.getSize(myUri, (width, height) => {this.setState({width, height})});

Answer (score 6):

To get a remote image dimensions, use `Image.getSize(uri, success, failure)`

Example of usage:

```js
Image.getSize(
    'https://link-to-image',
    (width, height) => {
        console.log(`Width: ${width}, Height: ${height}`);
    },
    (error) => console.error(error)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Image.resolveAssetSource()` can't get dimension from remote image by design and not to use for get dimension but for resolve image from `require()` which in jsbundle and have dimension info when building bundle as bonus.